# Como acceder a una etiqueta string de un xml usando Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, xml

Tengo el siguiente xml:

```
const body = '
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string>&lt;IGSS_CONSULTA_AFILIADOS_RUAP&gt;&lt;EXITO&gt;TRUE&lt;/EXITO&gt;&lt;FECHA_CONSULTA&gt;13/11/2020 12:39:37&lt;/FECHA_CONSULTA&gt;&lt;NUMERO_AFILIADO&gt;1234456&lt;/NUMERO_AFILIADO&gt;&lt;NOMBRE_AFILIADO&gt;YANES, LONA&lt;/NOMBRE_AFILIADO&gt;&lt;RELACIONES_LABORALES&gt;&lt;RELACION_LABORAL&gt;&lt;NUMERO_PATRONO&gt;43322222&lt;/NUMERO_PATRONO&gt;&lt;NOMBRE_PATRONO&gt;LOMAS&lt;/NOMBRE_PATRONO&gt;&lt;DIRECCION_EMPRESA&gt;SALVADOR&lt;/DIRECCION_EMPRESA&gt;&lt;NOMBRE_MUNICIPIO&gt;ANTIOQUIA&lt;/NOMBRE_MUNICIPIO&gt;&lt;NOMBRE_DEPARTAMENTO&gt;ANTIOQUIA&lt;/NOMBRE_DEPARTAMENTO&gt;&lt;TELEFONO_EMPRESA&gt;0&lt;/TELEFONO_EMPRESA&gt;&lt;/RELACION_LABORAL&gt;&lt;/RELACIONES_LABORALES&gt;&lt;/IGSS_CONSULTA_AFILIADOS_RUAP&gt;</string>
'
```

Necesito obtener los datos que estan en la equiqueta , porque ya hice un convertidor de xml a json que me servira para convertir los datos a json, pero no me los convierte bien porque necesito entrar al valor del `<string>`.

Entonces necesito recorrer ese xml y obtener el valor del string

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado? Tal vez te sirva leer [esto](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/Guide/Parsing_and_serializing_XML)

Answer (score 0):

¿Qué tal si usas una expresión regular para capturar todo lo que haya dentro de las etiquetas `<string>` y `</string>`?

Algo tipo:

```
let xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><string>&lt;IGSS_CONSULTA_AFILIADOS_RUAP&gt;&lt;EXITO&gt;TRUE&lt;/EXITO&gt;&lt;FECHA_CONSULTA&gt;13/11/2020 12:39:37&lt;/FECHA_CONSULTA&gt;&lt;NUMERO_AFILIADO&gt;1234456&lt;/NUMERO_AFILIADO&gt;&lt;NOMBRE_AFILIADO&gt;YANES, LONA&lt;/NOMBRE_AFILIADO&gt;&lt;RELACIONES_LABORALES&gt;&lt;RELACION_LABORAL&gt;&lt;NUMERO_PATRONO&gt;43322222&lt;/NUMERO_PATRONO&gt;&lt;NOMBRE_PATRONO&gt;LOMAS&lt;/NOMBRE_PATRONO&gt;&lt;DIRECCION_EMPRESA&gt;SALVADOR&lt;/DIRECCION_EMPRESA&gt;&lt;NOMBRE_MUNICIPIO&gt;ANTIOQUIA&lt;/NOMBRE_MUNICIPIO&gt;&lt;NOMBRE_DEPARTAMENTO&gt;ANTIOQUIA&lt;/NOMBRE_DEPARTAMENTO&gt;&lt;TELEFONO_EMPRESA&gt;0&lt;/TELEFONO_EMPRESA&gt;&lt;/RELACION_LABORAL&gt;&lt;/RELACIONES_LABORALES&gt;&lt;/IGSS_CONSULTA_AFILIADOS_RUAP&gt;</string>'

const regex = /.*<string>(.*)<\/string>.*/

let string = xml.replace(regex, '$1')
```

En la variable `string` tendrías el contenido que te interesa.

Recuerda hacer un formateo del código XML para quitar cualquier salto de línea ya que sino JS fallaría.